# Input without echo with Irvine32.lib

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

So what I need to accomplish is validate that the integer entered is within the accepted values (1-4) and not prompt the user that it is incorrect, rather wait until a valid entry is made. (If, Repeat or While statements are not allowed for this program )I have done so by using:

```
mov edx,OFFSET prompt           ;Prompt user for integer entry
    call WriteString
    Redo:                       ;Validate the integer
        call ReadInt
        cmp al,1                ;Wait for valid entry if integer is less than 1
        jl Redo
        cmp al,4                ;Wait for valid entry if integer is greater than 4
        jg Redo
        ret
```

However, my professor has mentioned that the input should be pre-checked and not displayed. Is this possible? Since you will be typing in the input, how do they just disappear? I have no idea how to do this or where to even start. It took me forever just to figure out how I was going to get the program to wait for valid entry and now have found out that I'm doing it wrong anyways. Can someone give me some pointers? Or a nudge in the right direction?

Here is the full code for the lock simulation.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc


.data
prompt BYTE 'Please press a button (1,2,3, or 4):', 0       
report1 BYTE 'The lock 2s count = 0', 0         
report2 BYTE 'The lock 2s count = 1', 0
report3 BYTE 'The lock 2s count = 2', 0
report4 BYTE 'The lock 2s count = 3', 0
report5 BYTE 'The lock is open!', 0
.code

main PROC
; Main program control procedure.
; Calls: DisplayMessage, GetButtonPress, Crlf, 
;       WriteString

Start:                          ;Beginning of the lock simulation
    call DisplayMessage         ;Display the starting lock 2s count
    call Crlf                   ;New line
    call GetButtonPress         ;Get user button choice
    cmp al, 1                   ;If user choice is 1 jump to State0
    je State0 
    cmp al, 2                   ;If user choice is 2 jump to State1
    je State1
    cmp al, 3                   ;If user choice is 3 jump to State0
    je State0
    cmp al, 4                   ;If user choice is 4 jump to State2
    je State2

State0:                         ;When the lock 2s count equals 0
    mov al, 0                   ;Make the AL register equal to 0 for message display
    call DisplayMessage         ;Display lock 2s count
    call Crlf                   ;New line
    call GetButtonPress         ;Get user button choice
    cmp al, 1                   ;If user choice is 1 jump to State0
    je State0
    cmp al, 2                   ;If user choice is 2 jump to State1
    je State1
    cmp al, 3                   ;If user choice is 3 jump to State0
    je State0
    cmp al, 4                   ;If user choice is 4 jump to State2
    je State2

State1:                         ;When the lock 2s count equals 1
    mov al,1                    ;Make the AL register equal to 1 for message display
    call DisplayMessage         ;Display lock 2s count
    call Crlf                   ;New line
    call GetButtonPress         ;Get user button choice
    cmp al, 1                   ;If user choice is 1 jump to State0
    je State0 
    cmp al, 2                   ;If user choice is 2 jump to State2
    je State2
    cmp al, 3                   ;If user choice is 3 jump to State0
    je State0
    cmp al, 4                   ;If user choice is 4 jump to State3
    je State3

State2:                         ;When the lock 2s count equals 2
    mov al,2                    ;Make the AL register equal to 2 for message display
    call DisplayMessage         ;Display lock 2s count
    call Crlf                   ;New line
    call GetButtonPress         ;Get user button choice
    cmp al, 1                   ;If user choice is 1 jump to State1
    je State1 
    cmp al, 2                   ;If user choice is 2 jump to State3
    je State3
    cmp al, 3                   ;If user choice is 3 jump to Terminal
    je Terminal
    cmp al, 4                   ;If user choice is 4 jump to State3
    je State3

State3:                         ;When the lock 2s count equals 3
    mov al,3                    ;Make the AL register equal to 3 for message display
    call DisplayMessage         ;Display lock 2s count
    call Crlf                   ;New line
    call GetButtonPress         ;Get user button choice
    cmp al, 1                   ;If user choice is 1 jump to State2
    je State2 
    cmp al, 2                   ;If user choice is 2 jump to State3
    je State3
    cmp al, 3                   ;If user choice is 3 jump to State0
    je State0
    cmp al, 4                   ;If user choice is 4 jump to State3
    je State3

Terminal:
    mov edx, OFFSET report5     ;Declare the lock as open
    call WriteString


    exit                        ;exit to operating system
main ENDP

;-------------------------------------------------------------
GetButtonPress PROC
;
; Prompts the user for button entry 
; Receives: None 
; Returns: An integer value to the AL register
; Calls: WriteString, ReadInt
;----------------------------------------------------------------
    mov edx,OFFSET prompt       ;Prompt user for integer entry
    call WriteString
    Redo:                       ;Validate the integer
        call ReadInt
        cmp al,1                ;Wait for valid entry if integer is less than 1
        jl Redo
        cmp al,4                ;Wait for valid entry if integer is greater than 4
        jg Redo
        ret
GetButtonPress ENDP

;-----------------------------------------------------------------
DisplayMessage PROC
;
; Displays the appropriate message concerning the lock 2s count
; Receives: The integer value in the AL register
; Returns: Nothing
; Calls: WriteString
;------------------------------------------------------------------
    cmp al,0                    ;Compare 1-3 to the AL register to display the proper message
    je Message1
    cmp al, 1
    je Message2
    cmp al, 2
    je Message3
    cmp al, 3
    je Message4

    Message1:                   ;If AL = 0 then the lock 2s count is 0
        mov edx,OFFSET report1
        call WriteString
        jmp Quit

    Message2:                   ;If AL = 1 then the lock 2s count is 1
        mov edx,OFFSET report2
        call WriteString
        jmp Quit

    Message3:                   ;If AL = 2 then the lock 2s count is 2
        mov edx,OFFSET report3
        call WriteString
        jmp Quit

    Message4:                   ;If AL = 3 then the lock 2s count is 3
        mov edx,OFFSET report4
        call WriteString

    Quit:                       ;Return to main PROC
        ret
DisplayMessage ENDP

END main
```

Comment: When you read a string on older operating systems, it first went to your buffer, and you were the one who displayed it. The question is on what you are testing it, and if this is the case of automatic display, whether there's a way (in your API) to disable the output.

Comment: Anyway, seeing `ReadInt` implementation could be a great help.

Comment: The ReadInt procedure is given from Irvine so we are not supposed to tamper with that part. We are going through Microsoft Visual Studios to run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - I actually needed to read the numbers as characters and use the author's ReadChar procedure instead as it does not echo to the screen.

I changed this section to:

```
;-------------------------------------------------------------
GetButtonPress PROC
;
; Prompts the user for button entry 
; Receives: None 
; Returns: A character value to the AL register
; Calls: WriteString, ReadChar
;----------------------------------------------------------------
    mov edx,OFFSET prompt       ;Prompt user for integer entry
    call WriteString
Redo:
    call ReadChar
    cmp al,'1'
    jl Redo
    cmp al,'4'
    jg Redo
    call WriteChar
    ret
GetButtonPress ENDP
```